# Without constructor how you initialize a class variables?

Tags: c#, oop

Without constructor how you initialize a class variables ? 
For Example , I have a class with two variables name as "x" and "y" data type as string. By creating an object for the class I need to initialize some value to these variables , without involvement of Constructor . Can u please any one help me ?

Comment: A constructor is ALWAYS called when you create an object.

Comment: @fejesjoco true to be more precise when you create an object and you do not have any constructor defined the default one `className()` is used.

Comment: The real question is, why do you *want* to do this?

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [Object Initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) feature:

```
var obj = new yourclass { x = "abc", y = "xyz" };
```

Although, this will work only if the variable `x` and `y` are public. Or, in other words, if they are accessible to the code where you are instantiating the class.

Comment: Note this only *syntactic sugar* for `var obj = new yourclass(); obj.x = "abc" ..`; it's still distinctly creating the object, then assigning properties/fields after the object has been created.

Comment: yes you are right. although, it would serve the purpose of a constructor in most cases.

Comment: Why is the question downvoted to hell is beyond me. This answer is exactly what I came looking for. My usecase is that I have a flat class, like `class A { public int x; public int y; }`, and making an explicit constructor for it felt very WET, so that's how I got here.

Comment: compared to constructor, it also will not work if variable is a get only (read only);

Answer (score 1):

You can put an initializer when you create the variables:

`private string foo = "val1";`

Comment: If he can modify the class definition he may as well give it a constructor.

Comment: Not necessarily... who knows what the restriction is?

Answer (score 0):

when you create an `object` for your `class` using `new` keyword default constructor will be invoked and all your class data members will be `initialised` to their `default type` values.

Ex:

```
Class Student
{
String strName;
String strAddress;
}

Student student1=new Student();//this will call default constructor
```

the above statement calls the Default Construdtor and it will initialise the values to their default types as below.

```
public Student
{
strName=String.Empty;
strAddress=String.Empty;
}
```

if you want to initialise your class variables with some specific values then you can  create parameterised constructor or initialise them normally.

```
String x="some value";
String y="some value";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the default values to private variables directly by initializing them as

```
public class A
{
  private int X= 5; //Like this
  private int Y= 6 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just like with a local variable like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    string x = "x";
    string y = "y";
}
```